# Vercel Failed to compile. React

Tags: reactjs, npm, error-handling, deployment, vercel

first, I was getting the same error for react-icons. now I am getting errors for the typewriter. it works fine on localhost. when I'm trying to `npm i` typewriter getting this error:

also tried `CI false` doesn't worked.

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! While resolving: cert@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"17.x" from typewriter-effect@2.18.2
    npm ERR! node_modules/typewriter-effect
    npm ERR!   typewriter-effect@"*" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! See /Users/Dave/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/Dave/.npm/_logs/2022-05-12T15_25_57_631Z-debug-0.log
```

```
    Cloning completed: 532.695ms
    Installing build runtime...
    Build runtime installed: 2.177s
    Looking up build cache...
    Build Cache not found
    Installing dependencies...
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
    added 1406 packages in 30s
    172 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
    Running "npm run build"
    > certauto@0.1.0 build
    > react-scripts build
    Creating an optimized production build...
    Failed to compile.
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'typewriter-effect' in '/vercel/path0/src/components'
    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: ****Update fixed issue***

the first issue was react 18.  replaced index.js code with -->

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const root=ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);

then -->

rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json

then -->

npm I --force

did --force to all packages that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me,

1. go to vercel
2. Go to your project
3. settings
4. install command = npm install --force or npm install --legacy-peer-deps